# SonarQube 6.4 Invalid value of sonar.sources

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, tfs-2015, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I use SonarQube Version 6.4 (build 25310) along with TFS2015 and the SonarQube extension for the TFS-Buildstep. All my project builds but one where i have folowing error in the log

> "ERROR: Invalid value of sonar.sources for >ProjectName:branch:ProjectKey:branch:AE8A3BE5-1E88-4D6F-BC7F-F9A927299B83"
>
> 2017-07-25T09:26:00.8647089Z ##[error]ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner >execution
> 2017-07-25T09:26:00.8647089Z ##[error]ERROR: The folder 'Path\path\path' does not exist for....

I tried to exclude thes folder but it didn't helped.

And i don't know why i have this error and why i get this strange number after the project key?

Comment: The strange number is the project GUID as defined in your .sln and in your .csproj files. Is this path existing or not? You are using the Scanner for MSBuild End step right? Would be great to have a bit more logs, in verbose mode (add /d:sonar.verbose=true to the begin step).

Comment: The path does not exist and we do not know why sonar is looking for it.
Yes we are using the 'SQ Scanner for MSBuild - End Analysis (new)'.

Errors:
Caused by: The folder <path> does not exist for does not exist for '<ProjName>:<Branch>:<ProjKey>:<Guid>' & java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectLock

Comment: May be we just found the reason for this error: Is it possible that ',' is not valid in a filename, because it does not get escaped?

Comment: @ZerQuetschMe : see [SONARMSBRU-199](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-199) . You should update your post with an actual example of such path and further details, that way one can make a clean answer for it.